# output format for mac address (C++, stringstream)

Tags: c++, string, format, stringstream

I found code:

```
static void PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[])
{
    printf("MAC Address: %02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n", 
        MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
}
```

this function prints MAC address like `00-53-45-00-00-00`

**My quesion:**

How to make such format while printing into `std::stringstream`?

**Update:**

Thank you all for your advices!

I do not know why, but some of solutions without `static_cast<unsigned int>` gave me strange characters like `☻-0→-0M-0Ы-0m-0╜` So I choose [boost version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587653/output-format-for-mac-address-c-stringstream/4587812#4587812) by **icecrime**:

```
void PrintMACaddressWithBoostFormat(unsigned char MACData[])
{
    boost::format fmt("%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X");

    for (int i = 0; i != 6; ++i)
    {
        fmt % static_cast<unsigned int>(MACData[i]);
    }

    std::stringstream valStream(fmt.str().c_str());

    //testing
    std::cout << "Boost version: " << valStream.str().c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

**Palmik**'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587653/output-format-for-mac-address-c-stringstream/4587714#4587714) works great, too;)

Thank you!

Comment: @Falmarri, i need to get MAC address in formated string like ipconfig prints in Windows by command ipconfig /all ;)

Comment: We know what you need, but what have you tried?

Comment: Why not write `+MACData[i]` rather than `static_cast<unsigned int>(MACData[i])`, and save yourself some typing?

Comment: I already read the Update. I said `+MACData[i]` not `MACData[i]`. It gives you an unsigned int, and is therefore [near-]equivalent.

Comment: (`MACData[i]` alone will request the stream to format the characters as human-readable, rather than as their numerical representations.)

Comment: @Tomalak thank you again;) I did not understand you at first time;)

Comment: Actually, sorry, it gives you an `int`, not `unsigned int`, but that's not a problem for you. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a little off topic, but I would personally use [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/format/index.html) :

```
boost::format fmt("%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X");
for (int i = 0; i != 6; ++i)
    fmt % static_cast<unsigned int>(MACData[i]);
std::cout << fmt << std::endl;
```

Comment: i do not know why your answer was downvoted; by me +1. your solution is only one gave me right result;) Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could do it like this (without changing the existing design of the app (I guess you can not, otherwise you would probably do it :)))

```
void printMacToStream(std::ostream& os, unsigned char MACData[])
{
    // Possibly add length assertion
    char oldFill = os.fill('0');

    os << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(MACData[0]);
    for (uint i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
        os << '-' << std::setw(2) << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>(MACData[i]);
    }

    os.fill(oldFill);

    // Possibly add:
    // os << std::endl;
}
```

Usage:

```
std::stringstream ss;
printMacToStream(ss, arrayWIthMACData);
```

Update: HEX format :)

Comment: Your '-' is on the wrong side of the MACData[i]. Should be `os  << '-' << MACData[i]`

Comment: thank you for answer) As i remember you was first and last version of your code works nice for now, too;) +1 by me; but you forget std::uppercase flag;)

Answer (score 1):

```
char prev = stream.fill('0');  // save current fill character

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
  stream << setw(2) << MACData[i] << '-';
stream << setw(2) << MACData[5];

stream.fill(prev);  // restore fill character
```

Comment: You need to set the stream to `hex` mode first.

Answer (score 1):

First you should convert your code to use C++ streams and manipulators, e.g.

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << MACData[0] ...
```

Then you should overload the `<<` operator for a stream on the left side and your class on the right.